# Clone subfolder using Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, repository

I read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951) to clone sub-folders of a repository but I am wondering if it is possible using Github Desktop to do this. [Github desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) allows cloning of repositories but I want to clone a single folder inside a repository.

Comment: I think its not possible till. Github desktop provides only basic features of git. You have to download whole repo and its all histories.